# Udacity function valid_year(year) -- Why is 1920 considered incorrect?

Tags: python

I'm getting the correct output on IDLE but the submission says it's incorrect. Thank you in advance for any suggestions/resolutions.

Code:

```
def valid_year(year):
    for i in range(1900,2021):
        if year.isdigit() and int(year)==i:
            return year
```

IDLE Output:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/33XKr.jpg

Incorrect. Your submission did not return the correct result for the
input '1920',. Your submission passed 7 out of 9 test cases.

Comment: When should a year be considered valid?

Answer (score 1):

Try this simpler version:

```
def valid_year(year):
    if not year.isdigit():
       return False
    return 1900 <= int(year) <= 2021
```

Comment: Actually the udacity's function returns `int` version of the year, not `True`, `False`. See the linked dup.

Answer (score 1):

Building on Burhan's answer, but returning the year:

```
def valid_year(year):
    if not year.isdigit():
        return False
    if 1900 <= int(year) <= 2021:
        return year
    return False
```

Comment: you can do `return year if 1900 <= int(year) <= 2021 else None` :)

Answer (score 0):

It is odd that it is passing 7 out of 9 tests. makes me think Udacity's grader can time out quite quickly - is it possible that it does not like having to check `year.isdigit()` on each iteration? It seems unlikey, but you could try:

```
def valid_year(year):
    if not year.isdigit():
        return "Invalid year."
    for i in range(1900, 2021):
        if i == int(year):
            return year
```